# bootstrap datetimepicker today dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

With the eternicode bootstrap-datetimepicker today uses MM/dd/yyyy.

How do I set datetimepicker to use dd/MM/yyyyy so that it highlights today correctly?

E.g. today is the 1st April , not 4th January.

Comment: this is a locale setting, see http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example2 and http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example5

Comment: Interesting, there does not seem to be a locale file for GB but thanks for drawing my attention to this.

Comment: the locale files for this picker are provided by momentjs. You can get them [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/master/locale)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#format), just set the `format` property.

See the [configuration](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/#configuration) section for different ways of setting options. For example (using `datetimepicker` instead of `datepicker`):

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
})
```

I would be wary of setting a specific format explicitly though - it would be better to honour the user's culture settings, unless you know for sure that all your users are happy to use the same format.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work as this is for the **datepicker** and not the **datetimepicker**. I have updated my original question.[link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) [link] (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: @MightyAtom: It *looks* like it should still work... or specify the format in the HTML as per http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example5

Comment: Specifying the format in the HTML does work for the date displayed in the text box, however, it does not resolve the original reported issue. When the control is activated it defaults to the wrong today date. For example it incorrectly highlights today as 4th of February instead of 2nd April. Any ideas?

Comment: @MightyAtom did you switch to another lib or did you find the solution? I'm having tons of issues with this picker

Comment: the locale files for this picker are provided by momentjs. You can get them [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/master/locale)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe have you opened an issue on github with whatever problems you are having?

Comment: Nope. We decided to use a different component at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Write two lines

.datepicker() then add new option for dateFormat
as per JQueryUI documentation
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

```
        $(".datetimepicker").datepicker();
        $(".datetimepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```